# Building a LoadMore or Show More with Python and React

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, sqlalchemy, react-redux

Application is a React/Redux frontend with an API built with Flask Python.

*Goal:* I'm building a list that instead of using pagination I would like to do a "show more" button.  The idea is that on ComponentDidMount it goes and gets the first set of 5 items from the API, then when a user clicks "show more" it will go out and populate the next 5 items and so on and so forth until the user has emptied the database and they can't load anymore.

*Issue:* I'm entirely unsure if this would be the best practice way to build this function.  I don't currently see any glaring negative ramifications, but I thought it'd be best to check with the experts here.

Given that this is an issue that a lot of people seem to have, I figured I'd post my approach for others.

*How I built it:*

**API Route in Python**
Description: This gets params from the action in redux.  It uses "offset" so that it always knows where to start it's query in the database.  It limits the results returned to 5 to keep the the load down.  Eventually I'll turn the limit into a parameter as well.

```
@app.route("/api/items", methods=["GET"])
def get_items():
    offset = request.args['offset'];
    items = Item.query.order_by(Item.name).offset(offset).limit(5)
    items_serialized = []
    for item in items:
        items_serialized.append(item.serialize())
    if items:
        return jsonify(items=items_serialized)
```

**Function from my React component:** 
I have a list inside of my Component that takes listData and prints out all the list items.  I won't get into the details on this, but this is how I handle the load more functionality.

- Offset - uses `listData.length` to keeps it place.  That way I don't have to use a counter.
- .Then() - Since I use an Axios Promise in my actionCreators, I realized I could wait for the promise response to return with `.then()` and set my state from that point [this avoids the error where it's `null` or pending...].

I then concat my listData with itemsList with all duplicates removed via the function _uniqBy using the id of each item.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.updateListData()
  }

updateListData = () => {
    const offset = this.state.listData.length;
    this.props.fetchItems(offset).then(() => {
      this.setState(state => {
        const itemsList = _.uniqBy(state.listData.concat(this.props.itemsList), 'id')
        return { listData: itemsList }
      });
    });
  }

onLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState({
      loadingMore: true,
    });
    this.updateListData();
  };
```

**Actions and Reducers:**
Here's a general description of how it works for all the redux using people.

- fetchItems does a GET towards the API with a param of offset passed in.
- Reducer either returns itemsList or an error to my store state.

I haven't fully cleaned up the code on list and I feel like I've made some errors typing out the approach, but hopefully someone can take something away from this because I was really struggling.  In addition, if people can tell me if this is the right approach that would be great?

Comment: Perhaps the answer would be to use something like a Cursor within the database?  Essentially trying to "hold my place" in the db as I load more?

Comment: I've now edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: Regarding if that's the right approach or not, offset may suffer performance degradation, if you serve *a lot* of pages and the offset grows large. In that case the "seek" method may prove more performant: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Comment: This is great!  Just need to figure out how to implement with Sqlalchemy and Postgresql and might have a better way of pulling this data.